# Sharepoint top navigation img for selected link

Tags: css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am trying to set an img that points to the selected link on the top navgation of my SharePoint page. Could someone help me with the CSS please?

[image]

The triangle under the Visual Identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this you can achieve it via pure css with (notice the nav li.selected a:after style definition).

Here's a working snippet

```css
* {
  background: #454545;
}
nav {
  width: 500px;
  height: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul {
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 12px;
  position: relative;
}
nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 11px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav li.selected a {
  color: red;
}
nav li.selected a:after {
  border-left: solid transparent 10px;
  border-right: solid transparent 10px;
  border-bottom: solid #fff 10px;
  bottom: -12px;
  content: " ";
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/page1/">Experience</a>
    </li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="/page2/">Visual Identity</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/page3/">tone of voice</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```